# XAML: Under the Hood

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Well, i must admit, still sometimes XAML seems a bit mysterious to me. The thing is, i always liked to debug through the C# code (setting lots of breakpoints in them) to get the idea of "what is happening" and "how is it happening". But with declarative XAML syntax that's not an option. I think you'll agree that to work with XAML, or to be precise, to work with/understand some existing XAML code you got to "already know" how things work with XAML declaration. There is just no way you can know/learn  things investigating the execution of your application code. So i'm more than interested to take a look through XAML inside-out, as detailed as possible. I'm NOT talking about "learning" XAML, I know the basic stuff. May be i can provide some examples to clarify the sort of things i'm looking for -

- Compared to C# code how an object gets instantiated when we use them in XMAL? Are they stored in managed heap? Same way as C# code-instantiated objects?
- How the properties get set while using Mark-Up Extension syntax for Data/Command Binding?
- When any property of an INotifyPropertyChanged type gets updated, how the Binding instatnce inside the XAML syntax updates the itself? How exactly it gets notified it at the first place, & by whom?
- A viewmodel can be set as the DataContext of a view at runtime by defining Typed DataTemplate, like -
  `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:AccountsViewModel}">

       <views:Accounts/>

  </DataTemplate>`
   How does it happen actually? What are the rules for setting DataContext other than searching for the DataContext property upward the logical tree?
- How the whole template things (DataTemplate, ControlTemplate & ItemsPanelTemplate) are treated/resolved at run time.
- etc. etc. etc.

So if you are good/experienced/expert in XAML what would you suggest (links, articles, blogposts, books whatever) as reference that helps getting clear & deeper understanding about how XAML works "under-the-hood"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You raise some interesting questions, but this is a very broad question and unlikely to get a definitive answer - which makes it a slightly bad fit for StackOverflow.  However, something that might help your understanding somewhat is that XAML is a *serialization* of the objects that make up the UI.  When you put `<Button...` in your xaml, this will result in an instance of the `Button` class at runtime, when the UI is created.  So, "debugging Xaml" wouldn't make sense, as Xaml isn't executed (it's not really "code" and doesn't contain instructions).

Comment: Please DO NOT close the question. Try to understand that all those bullet points are NOT my questions. Those represents only the hints about the kind of reference i'm looking for. My ONLY question is the final one in the last para - "...what would you suggest...?"

Comment: Most likely: Google, MSDN, and the WPF bible (http://www.amazon.com/WPF-4-Unleashed-Adam-Nathan/dp/0672331195).

Comment: @DanPuzey: thanks Dan for your opinion. I guessed same about that "debugging through XAML" topic. I've read Nathan's WPF-4-Unleashed (http://www.amazon.com/WPF-4-Unleashed-Adam-Nathan/dp/0672331195). It didn't help much. MacDonald's Pro WPF in C# 2010 (http://www.apress.com/9781430272052) is a LOT better. But even that doesn't seem satisfying when you consider the XAML alone.

Comment: Have another, closer look into the "XAML Demystified" chapter of "WPF 4 Unleashed". In my opinion it explains a lot.

Comment: @Clemens: thanks Clemens. i will. right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most can be explained by don't thinking of XAML as a real programming language, more like a declarative language. Everything you do in xaml, can be made in C# aswell, and in fact this is whats happening.

> Compared to C# code how an object gets instantiated when we use them
>   in XMAL? Are they stored in managed heap? Same way as C#
>   code-instantiated objects?

Yes because they are just c# objects. Most resources are stored in a hibernated state, i rememberd the word inflated somewhere. Converter or other "direct" c# objects are created when they are needed. Important here is that these resources are usually shared, so they will get created only once.

> How the properties get set while using Mark-Up Extension syntax for Data/Command Binding?

This again depends on where you use the markup extension. In a Style? In a Template? In a instanced user control like a window? Usually they are evaluated when you actually need them. It wouldn't make sense to evaluate them, when the inflated style is stored in the actual resource dictionary. They get evaluated when you actually use the style on an object.

> When any property of an INotifyPropertyChanged type gets updated, how
>   the  Binding instatnce inside the XAML syntax updates the itself? How
>   exactly it gets notified it at the first place, & by whom?

By the binding engine. WPF checks if your DataContext inherits the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, attaches to the event provided by the interface and listens to any changes. If such an event is raised, the binding engine will just call the getter again.

> How does it happen actually? What are the rules for setting DataContext 
>   other than searching for the DataContext property upward
>   the logical tree?

In short: None other. Datacontext is simply an inherited attached property. If you don't re set it on a child control, it will take the value the parent has until it reached the root. The only exception to this are `ContentControls` and `ContentPresenter` they will not inherit the DataContext but will change them depending on the content. So these controls always have by default the Content as their DataContext.

> How the whole template things (DataTemplate, ControlTemplate & ItemsPanelTemplate) are treated/resolved at run time.

Simply spoken: Everytime WPF finds a non ui object, it tries to find a DataTemplate for the given type. In an ItemsControl for example: You can bind a list of `MyClass`; unless you provide an explicit DataTemplate or DataTemplateSelector it will search the resource tree upwards for an implicit style. Again remember that this already does not happen in XAML, but on the C# objects that was generated out of the xaml.

> And is it by any means possible (at present or near future) to debug
>   through XAML code?

How do you think you can debug something that is not executed, but evaluated on compile time?

Please don't take this as 100% correct. Over the Years this is what i gathered of informations about XAML and the usage. If you have any corrections or find something that is clearly wrong. Please tell me, we are all here to learn and i always learn new things about the stuff i use :)